# Bitbucket - Revoke Oauth Authorization API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

In bitbucket, i have created oauth consumer & implemented authentication flow (Authorization Code Grant) https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#1--authorization-code-grant--4-1-

Need help with revoke authorization api

After some point of time, if user wants to revoke this authorization it can be achieved in bitbucket website (attached img reference)

[revoke authorizarion from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKtyS.png)

I couldn't find the rest api reference to revoke app authorization from my website itself. Kindly assist me on how to revoke the authorization

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint in the rest API for this at the moment.
You can vote for this issue, so bitbucket will implement it at one point: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22302